# @author when extensively modifying someone else's code

Tags: upgrade, author

What is the accepted way to update the @author info when you are given someone else's code to upgrade with new functionality, not just fixing bugs?  I'd say by the time I'm done with some of these codes, at least 1/3 of the code is what I added.  The code's not kept in a repository, and the old version won't be used anymore, so this doesn't really qualify as a 'fork'.

Comment: Leave both author's name on it, with dates.

Comment: Multiple @author lines then?

Comment: It's what I would do, even if I replaces 100% of the code.